# my hp pavilion can't access the internet after windows 7 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, hp-pavilion

upgraded my HP pavilion notebook from Vista to 7, no access to internet, HP tech support worked on it for an hour, then referred me to my ISP, who worked for 90 min and referred me to microsoft, my desktop is still running XP and connects fine. help please?

Answer (score 0):

Please post:

1. `ipconfig /all`
2. `ping` your default gateway (you can get this from ipconfig /all, it will be the same default gateway as your XP machine)
3. `ping www.google.com`
4. `tracert www.google.com`

You don't have Symantec Antivirus installed, do you? Sometimes the firewall service gets corrupted and then blocks everything out on port 80 and 443.

You may want to put a USB into the computer and get the output of the commands by redirecting output to a text file. You could then edit your question with the results. Example:

```
ipconfig /all > e:\ipconfig.txt
```